# Unexpected behavior with Django LiveServerTestCase using SQLite3

Tags: django, selenium, testing, sqlite, functional-testing

I am using [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/test/testcases/#LiveServerTestCase) for functional tests with selenium in a Django app. I am using sqlite3 as a backend for local development, and I'm running the tests with a local development server on port `8081`.

I wrote a test for user registration, and when I run this test more than once, I see that the test fails because my form throws an error saying the user already exists. When I delete the sqlite3 database file and run re-run migrations I can run the test again and it works fine (but running again will fail).

I thought that this class would use a new database each time a test within the class was run, but I am getting errors.

My question is:

**Is there another way to run the tests with `LiveServerTestCase` so that I don't have to delete the sqlite3 database each time I want to run the test?**

Edit:

Here are some other parts of the documentation that my question is based on:

**LiveServerTestCase**

> LiveServerTestCase does basically the same as TransactionTestCase with
>   one extra feature: it launches a live Django server in the background
>   on setup, and shuts it down on teardown. This allows the use of
>   automated test clients other than the Django dummy client such as, for
>   example, the Selenium client, to execute a series of functional tests
>   inside a browser and simulate a real user’s actions.

**TransactionTestCase**

> Resetting the database to a known state at the beginning of each test
>   to ease testing and using the ORM.